# Is there a way to convert date which is in string(varchar) in a table to date(Date variable) without deleting data?

Tags: sql-server

I Have stored the date as a string format in my database (EX:01-July-2017)
Is there a way to Change that to proper date format in sql server since I have to use Range eventually

```
 Create table xus(Date varchar(40) )
 #my input is 01-July-2017
```

I need to use Range operator so I need to convert it into proper date format without deleting data

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: SELECT CAST([Date] AS DATE) FROM xus

Comment: `ALTER TABLE xus ALTER COLUMN [Date] Date`

Comment: @MartinSmith but that doesn't change the existing values,right? I need to change the existing values too

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Add new date column
ALTER TABLE xus
ADD NewDate DATETIME

-- Migrate data
UPDATE xus
SET NewDate = CONVERT( DATETIME, OldDate )
-- If any errors at this stage, you may need to fix them individually for each problematic record. 
-- ISDATE function may help with this

-- Drop current date column (which is VARCHAR)
ALTER TABLE xus
DROP COLUMN OldDate

-- Rename New column to be old column enter code here
EXEC sp_RENAME 'xus.NewDate' , 'OldDate', 'COLUMN'
```